# how to save date and time when we click on a button in android

Tags: android

Please help me, we have entered some data in edit text along with that automatically is it possible to save date either internally/ externally/ in database and time when we click in save button after filling the form in android.

Please help me with this thanks in before.

Answer (score 0):

Use SharedPreferences.. That's also help to save . [Here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm) is the sample